# best practice when using fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am very new to Android. I have several buttons, when I click on them I get some list of items. Independently of the clicked button, the list views are exactly the same, the only thing that is changing is the remote `url` called to charge the items. Is there a better way than using fragments to do that ? Or is it possible to add some `url` parameter in the getView  method of each adapter (I am using an adapter for each fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

You can't pass additional arguments to Adapter.getView() directly, but you can pass additional information (e.g. the URL or the items you've loaded from that URL) as a constructor parameter to your Adapter sub-class and access that from within the implementation of getView().

From the limited amount of detail you've provided, I would suggest having a single Fragment class handling the display of your list, and passing the URL to load the data from to the fragment as an argument along these lines:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

  private static String ARG_URL = "url";

  public static MyListFragment create(String url) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_URL, url);
    MyListFragment fragment = new MyListfragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }

  ...
}
```

The fragment can then handle asynchronously loading the data and displaying of the list.

As far as best practice goes, I tend to hide the creation / argument passing part in a static factory method like this, so the code that wants to use the fragment doesn't need to know how exactly the arguments are marshalled into a Bundle, and you can handle validation of the arguments, default values etc if necessary.

Comment: thanks, sorry if the following is quite naive, I don't much of `android`. I have a tab listener, so when I click one some tab, I call `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.$some_id, new SomeFragment()).commit();` am I supposed to pass the url in this instance, and then pass it to `onCreateView` that delegates to your  `create` method ?

Comment: Along the lines of fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.$some_id, SomeFragment.create(targetUrlForThisTab)).commit(); You can then access the URL in onCreateView() using getArguments().get(ARG_URL).